react native this.getNativeComponent undefined error
I'm encountering an issue with my React Native project where I'm getting the following error during runtime
TypeError: this.getNativeComponent is not a function (it is undefined)
This error occurs when trying to render a map using the react-native-maps library. The err
Additional Details
The issue specifically arises when using the marker functionality in the react-native-maps library. Here are the key points:

Error Specifics: The error TypeError: this.getNativeComponent is not a function (it is undefined) only appears when trying to use markers. If markers are not used, the app runs without any issues.

Development Environment: Running npx react-native run-android works perfectly on my emulator, including the marker functionality.

Deployment Issue: The problem occurs when I build the app for release. When I generate a debug APK and install it on a device, the app crashes with the mentioned error when markers are used.


I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Configuration Checks:

Verified that all dependencies and plugins are correctly specified in the build.gradle files.

Ensured that react-native-maps is correctly linked and included in the project.



Running in Development:

Ran npx react-native run-android to launch the app in an emulator. The app works perfectly, including the marker functionality on the map.


Building and Deploying:

Built a debug APK using ./gradlew assembleDebug and installed it on a device. The app installs successfully but crashes with the TypeError: this.getNativeComponent is not a function error when trying to use markers on the map.


Reviewing and Modifying Code:

Reviewed and modified MainApplication.kt, settings.gradle, and other configuration files to ensure everything is correctly set up.



What Was Expected?
I expected the app to function the same way on the deployed APK as it does when run directly in the development environment through the emulator. Specifically, I expected the markers on the map to render without any errors.
What Actually Resulted?
Despite the app running perfectly in the emulator with npx react-native run-android, the deployed debug APK crashes when using the marker functionality on the map, with the error message TypeError: this.getNativeComponent is not a function (it is undefined).
Request for Assistance
I need help understanding why there is a discrepancy between the development environment and the deployed APK. Any insights on how to resolve this issue so that the marker functionality works correctly in the deployed app would be greatly appreciated.
here is my code
APP.tsx file
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Region,Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { FAB, PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import LocationMarkers from './DataBase/LocationMarkers';
import ClosestMarkerFinder from './DataBase/ClosestMarkerFinder';
import Interfaceoption from './aboutUI/Interfaceoption';
import {
  requestLocationPermission,
  getCurrentLocation,
  startWatchingPosition,
  stopWatchingPosition
} from './aboutlocation/getpermission';
import testDB from './DataBase/testDB';
import WeatherView from './aboutUI/wheatherView';
import useWheatherData from './DataBase/wheather';



function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const mapViewRef = useRef<MapView>(null);
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState<Region | null>(null);
  const [watchId, setWatchId] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<number>(0);
  const [fabActive, setFabActive] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [countDistance, setDistance] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState<MarkerData | null>(null);
  const [marker, setMarker] = useState<any[]>([]); // 수정 필요
  const { data } = useWheatherData();
 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await testDB(); // 데이터 가져오기
        setMarker(data);
        console.log(data,"fetchDATA의 DB 값 ")
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111Error fetching data:', err);
      }
    };
   
    
    
    const fetchLocation = async() =>{

      try{
        const failcheck = await requestLocationPermission()
        if (failcheck){
          getCurrentLocation(setCurrentPosition, mapViewRef);
        }
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log("2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222Error fetching data:",err)
      }

    }
    
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      fetchLocation()
      fetchData(); // 데이터 가져오기 함수 호출
    }
    
  }, []);

  const goToCurrentLocation = () => {
    console.log("이동");
    if (currentPosition && mapViewRef.current) {
      mapViewRef.current.animateToRegion(currentPosition, 500);
    } else {
      Alert.alert("Location not available", "Current location is not available yet.");
    }
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(mode, "작동되는 부분");
    if (mode === 0) {
      setFabActive(false);
      goToCurrentLocation();
    } else if (mode === 1) {
      setFabActive(true);
      startWatchingPosition(setCurrentPosition, mapViewRef, setWatchId);
    } else {
      setFabActive(false);
      stopWatchingPosition(watchId, setWatchId);
      goToCurrentLocation();
    }
    setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode + 1) % 3);
  };

  interface MarkerData {
    title: string;
    result: number;
    direction: string;
    child: number;
    adult: number;
    Disabled: number;
    pet: number;
  }

  const handleMarkerSelected = (markerData: MarkerData) => {
    setSelectedMarker(markerData);
    if (markerData !== null) {
      setDistance(markerData.result);
    } else {
      setDistance(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, position: "static" }}>
          <MapView
            ref={mapViewRef}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={false}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 37.5665,
              longitude: 126.9780,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          >
         //if i don use this part then no error 
         <LocationMarkers markerdata={marker} />
           
            
          </MapView>
         
          <WeatherView weatherData={data}/>
          <FAB
            icon={"crosshairs-gps"}
            style={[styles.fab, { backgroundColor: fabActive ? '#005AFF' : '#FFFFFF' }]}
            onPress={handleButtonClick}
          />
          <Interfaceoption numbervalue={selectedMarker} />
          <ClosestMarkerFinder currentPosition={currentPosition} onMarkerFound={handleMarkerSelected} />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fab: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 15,
    bottom: 15,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#007AFF',
  }
});

export default App;

//locationmarker.js file
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

export default function LocationMarkers({ markerdata }) {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (markerdata && markerdata.length > 0) {
      setMarkers(markerdata.map((location, index) => ({
        key: index,
        coordinate: {
          latitude: location.latitude,
          longitude: location.longitude,
        },
        title: location.location_title,
      })));
    }
  }, [markerdata]);

  return (
    <>
      {markers.map((marker) => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.key}
          coordinate={marker.coordinate}
          title={marker.title}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

my pakage.json
{
  "name": "mapapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.15.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.7",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.84",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4"
}

i do not know why it's keep happen

there is an open issue with workaround provided here: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4861 but I would recommend forking the package or holding on to a version of the package with the mod locally until it's fixed in the main repository

I have the same issue, deleting the errored line from the package in node modules looks like the only solution I could find so far but I really don't want to do that...
